# How do I intelligently re-indent Clojure in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm new to Clojure and new to Emacs.

Is there an Emacs short-cut to intelligently re-indent the whole file?
if not, is there at least a way to indent selected regions left or right?

I feel like I'm back in the stone age repeatedly pressing the arrows

Answer (score 42, accepted):

<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd> selects the entire buffer.  <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> reindents the selected region.

Comment: And `C-M-q` runs `indent-sexp`, which I also find quite useful, especially in combination with `beginning-of-defun` (which lives on `C-M-a`).

Comment: With paredit mode, you can just press `M-q`, which reindents the whole defun without moving point around.

Comment: nitpick., its `C-x h` for selecting entire buffer

Comment: C-M-\ should simply be a mapping to `indent-region`. Selecting should not be necessary.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd> (select all) followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> (to indent)

Answer (score 8):

cider-format-buffer command (Since cider 0.9.0)

Answer (score 3):

When you capture data from a sequence like `C-u C-c C-e`
(`cider-eval-last-sexp`), the raw data output to your buffer can be
unwieldy to inspect/work with.  And the normal code-indenting commands
(mentioned in answers here) don't handle it well.

For handling results from such evaluated expressions, try
`cider-format-edn-region`.

As a concrete example, have you ever tried reformatting your
`~/.lein/profiles.clj`?  This is pretty hard to do and keep
consistent, until you discover `cider-format-edn-region`.  Take
caution that it will, however, remove any comments.

Comment: I've never found reformatting my `profiles.clj` to be hard, as a consequence of using `paredit` and `aggressive-indent`. This approach has the advantage of not removing comments, which I have a lot of.

Answer (score 0):

Use [cljfmt](https://github.com/weavejester/cljfmt) for many configurable ways to reformat/reindent.  It has an Emacs plugin, but also can be run via `lein`.